# android getLaskKnownLocation null

Tags: android

I have tried both GPS and Network Provider but they give null location for getLastKnownLocation.  I do not get any onLocationChanged either.  I am trying from my apartment where the cell signal is strong.  I can even browse internet well and download and install apps fine from market.

I have read few threads on same topic but their suggestion seems I already have tried.

Here is my code snippet.

```
 public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(null == locationManager) {
        Log.d(TAG, "location manager NULL");
    }
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this); 

    // Initialize with the last known location
    Location lastLocation = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); 
    if (lastLocation != null)
        onLocationChanged(lastLocation);
    else
        Log.i(TAG, "null LastKnownLocation");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            0,0, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "requested location updates");

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

As per log:

```
mitenm@pinkydebian:/media/sf_E_DRIVE/tmp$ adb logcat LocationNotifierService:* *:S
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/LocationNotifierService(30866): null LastKnownLocation
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): gps provider enabled:true
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): network provider enabled:true
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): onCreate
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): requested location updates
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): requested location updates
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): requested location updates
```

I have "unlock receiver" so when I unlock my screen I request location updates which is working as expected from logs.  But the onLocationChanged method is not getting invoked.

I have permission added to manifest both for fine and coarse.

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: Have you enabled location services on your device, have you added the permissions in manifest, do you get any errors if so post the log trace. There are plenty of tutorials online that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

> android getLaskKnownLocation null

As Per Google Doc

`getLaskKnownLocation`  Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider otherwise it returns null.

It means it shows the cached data.If you are running your application on device which has never queried for location data before will have empty cache thats why you are getting null.

> do not get any onLocationChanged either.

Make sure you have enabled Network Provider for location.

Use below Snippet.

```
if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected() || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()) {

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Constants.CONNECTED = true;

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, this);
    } else {
        Constants.CONNECTED = false;

        Toast.makeText(
        context, "Please enable Wireless networks in Location Setting!!", 10000).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: These log statements print that they are enabled.  I omitted them from snippet to make things bit short and clear: Log.d(TAG, "gps provider enabled:" + locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
  Log.d(TAG, "network provider enabled:" + locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));  thanks. Miten.

Comment: Here are some log statements: mitenm@pinkydebian:/media/sf_E_DRIVE/tmp$ adb logcat LocationNotifierService:* *:S
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/LocationNotifierService(30866): null LastKnownLocation
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): gps provider enabled:true
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): network provider enabled:true
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): onCreate
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): requested location updates
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): requested location updates
D/LocationNotifierService(30866): requested location updates